# Order By a field being equal to a specific value?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE x='abc' OR y=0;
```

How can I prioritize the rows so that cases where `x='abc'` are ordered FIRST?  If `y=0` but `x!='abc'`, I want those rows to come after cases where `x='abc'`.

Can this be accomplished with a simple ORDER BY clause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
WHERE x='abc' 
    OR y=0
order by case when x='abc' then 0 else 1 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a case statement:

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN column_one = 0 THEN 0 
         WHEN column_two = 'ADMIN' THEN 1 
    END AS multi_column 
FROM sometable
ORDER BY multi_column;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY FIELD(x,'abc',x)`