# ORDER BY followed by a number

Tags: sql, sqlite

I took this query from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453206/order-by-a-field-being-equal-to-a-specific-value).

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
WHERE x='abc' 
    OR y=0
order by case when x='abc' then 0 else 1 end;
```

This query supposedly will prioritize x='abc' cases. But I'm really confused why is this happening? Isn't ORDER BY followed by a column name or column number? Also, I researched on the syntax of ORDER BY and they don't tell anything about this. I also tried something like this but it says: "1st ORDER BY term out of range - should be between 1 and 1":

```
SELECT A
FROM B
ORDER BY 2
```

So, can anyone explain this query or at least point to a good documentation? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when an `ORDER BY` clause is followed by a number, this number will be referenced to the column in the `(number)` position.

The `ORDER BY` followed by a `CASE EXPRESSION` is called conditional ordering, each column will get the value `0` when `x` is equal to `abc` and when its not it will get the value `1`. After that, the ordering is in `ASC` , so `0` will always be prioitized before `1`.

It will be something like this:

```
 x  |   y   | .... | Here is the new value that will order the query
abc     1              0
ayr     0              1
acz     1              1
.........
```

So, basically it's like generating a new value.

Comment: But can it be combined with the normal ordering? Also, why such a good feature not properly documented?

Comment: Because it's not standard SQL, it's a way to trick the ordering, and yea, of course it can, this is a valid order by: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN x = 'abc' THEN 0 else 1 END, x DESC, y ASC....Another_case_if_you_want` @SidGo

Comment: @SidGo - It ***is*** documented.  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html  Under `The ORDER BY Clause` it states that positional ordering *only* works if the ORBER BY expression is `a constant integer` *(not a function, a field, expression, or CASE statement)*.

Comment: Thank you. This is really a very useful feature and I'm very surprised that I can hardly find this on the internet. I really need to find a good documentation about this in case there are more usage.

Comment: @MatBailie Oh. But what I specifically mean is from SQL tutorials because that's where beginner begins. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @SidGo That is not standard beginners SQL, so you are not supposed to find it there.